# Subdomain redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched a lot but I've failed.

I had a subdomain like

```
http://subdomain.domain.it
```

that pointed to

```
http://domain.it/subdomain/
```

And I've changed my subfolder to

```
sub-domain/
```

So I've decided to change my subdomain in

```
http://sub-domain.domain.it
```

and point it to

```
http://domain.it/sub-domain/
```

but I can't to rewrite my .htaccess to this rule.
I must do it cause my subdomain has a good position on google but this position points to http://subdomain.domain.it while now all my content is in http://sub-domain.domain.it.

This is my actual .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)?$ page.php [L]
```

Thanks to all

Comment: What's your current htaccess file look like?

Comment: I've updated with my .htaccess. I've just redirect all requests to my page.php....